# LaTeX not rendering?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

LaTeX seems to not be rendering at the moment.

- Is this just me? (Chrome on 64-bit Linux)
- Can we have a 'regenerate TeX' button like at MathOverflow?
- Maybe even a 'render source' button or GET option for when things are broken?

Comment: I've had the same problem with Chrome on Windows, usually on comments or answers I've posted.  Sometimes refreshing works, sometimes it doesn't.  I just went back to the page where it most recently happened and it worked fine.  A 'regenerate TeX' button would be nice, if refreshing doesn't already do this.

Comment: No-repro. Have you tried Shift + Refresh?

Comment: Refresh didn't do it, shift-refresh didn't do it, restarting browser didn't do it.

Comment: @Charles: Which version of Chrome are you using? But "Not rendering" do you mean `[Math processor error]`?

Comment: Latest beta channel for Debian/Ubuntu. When I open a page I see the grayed-out source for a moment (as usual), but then rather than replacing it with rendered formulas it simply leaves a gap in the page.

Comment: @Charles: [We do not support beta browsers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported/56192#56192). Will it render on a non-beta browser?

Comment: On Firefox, yes; on Chrome, no.

Comment: Today I see only "math processor error". Everything is normal on MO... I am using Firefox. What's up?

Comment: @tetrapharmakon: Yes, I just got the same thing.  It happened to me right after a security update.  It's a real pity -- now it won't display on Chrome (blank) or Firefox ([Math Processing Error]).  And this is totally standard Firefox 3.6.11.